# Return 2d char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, char

I want to take a 2D char array as an input in a function (actually my 2D array is global and the function doesn't have inputs) , change the values in it and then return another 2D char array.

```
char stoixeia[50][7];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

.
.
.

```
if (strcmp(answer, "Gift")==0) 
        {
            gift();
        } 


char gift ()
    {
     int i,j,m;
     int wrong=0;
     int k=0;
     char usern[50];
     while(wrong=0)
    {

     printf("Enter the username that you want to Gift:\n");
     scanf("%s", &usern);
     for (i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
     if (*usern==stoixeia[i][0])
     {
     wrong=1;
     k=i;
     }
     }

     }  
      m=strlen(usern);
      for(i=0; i<m; i++)
      {
        stoixeia[k][6]= stoixeia[k][6] + 10;
      }



      return stoixeia[50][7];

     }
```

My thought was that if i declare my array as a global one everything would change in my functions and the array will get "updated". The compiler doesn't show any errors but when I run the programm and my `answer` is `Gift` the .exe stops working. Can you suggest me anything? Thank you

Comment: 1 `stoixeia[50][7];` is out of bound. 2. to return an _array_, you need to have a `char **`, at least.

Comment: BTW `while(wrong=0)` --> `while(wrong==0)`

Comment: @SouravGhosh what do you mean "is out of bound"? it is under the libraries

Comment: @BLUEPIXY oh yeah, now it doesnt crashes but somehow when i enter a username in `usern` it doesnt find anything and it always asks me to give another username

Comment: "_My thought was that if i declare my array as a global one everything would change in my functions and the array will get "updated"._" -- Yes. True. So, you do not need to return the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function must be like this:

**You don't need to return a value because you change directly the global variable.**

```
void gift ()
{
    int i,j,m;
    int wrong=0;
    int k=0;
    char usern[50];
    while(wrong==0) /* replace = by ==*/
    {

        printf("Enter the username that you want to Gift:\n");
        scanf("%s", usern);
        for (i=0; i<50; i++)
        {
            if (usern[i]==stoixeia[i][0])
            {
                wrong=1;
                k=i;
            }
        }
    }  
    m=strlen(usern);
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        stoixeia[k][6]= stoixeia[k][6] + 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: compilers shows me: [Warning] return makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: ok, thank you! i will try it!
*also how should i declare the function?

Comment: you need to compare usern and stoixeia[i] ? or only the first character?

Comment: i want to compare the string (`usern`) with the first column of the array `stoixeia[i][0]`

Comment: first line or first column?

Comment: type of `stoixeia` isn't `char**`.

Comment: first column of the array

Comment: but how should i declare `gift` after rename it to char **gift

Comment: you mean how to call it?

Comment: look, i changed ` if (usern[i]==stoixeia[i][0])` as you said and the function works perfectly. I didnt put `char **`

Comment: so you can use it as a `void` function

Comment: Please use proper indentation and drop the `&` from `scanf`.

Comment: @CoolGuy: you are right, I don't see the `&` in scanf, indentation is fixed, please see the updated answer

Comment: "_`/* you should initialize stoixeia to 0 via memcpy for example */`_" -- Why? `stoizeia` is a global array and it is automatically initialized to 0.

Comment: why did you remove & in `scanf`? also thank you for your help, i think that it works now :) @developer

Comment: Notes: 1)A `do...while` loop is better in this case. 2)`for (i=0; i<50; i++)` should probably be `for(int i = 0, len = strlen(usern); i < len; i++)` 3) To @sniperalex117, if you say what *exactly* you're trying to achieve, it is easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned use `**gift()` see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/9508/) for some more information